# Word Choice: "is put"

Tags: word-choice

I am currently revising an essay that I received feedback from my Japanese teacher about, and am having trouble working out what word she wanted me to use in a particular spot.

> 日本では自動販売機はかっこよくて便利だと考えられ、一般的に積極的に**見られて**いるような気がする。

The bold word is the one that she wanted me to fix, and the comment that she wrote was "is put". I don't necessarily even need the word itself, so much as a concrete English meaning, as I can't figure out what "is put" is referring to in terms of Japanese meaning.

Incidentally, I am finishing the revision tonight, but even if I submit it, knowing what word fits better would be very helpful.

I have tried to look up "put" in various online dictionaries, but have not found any Japanese verb that sounds right in that context, and the other words that I can think of to replace it with (認められ、受け、視され、思われ) don't have a meaning that resembles "put" enough to be likely to be what she had in mind.

I may be overthinking it, but I would really appreciate guidance towards a better search term or the Japanese word itself (though the latter is less preferable because I don't get a chance to learn as much that way, and it is homework after all).

Comment: `積極的に見られている` は、意味がよくわからないですね。。 「積極的」は"positive"の訳ですか。この場合は「[肯定的]{こうていてき}に」じゃないですかね？「肯定的に捉えられている・見られている・受け入れられている」って感じで。。。（先生は、「積極的に置かれている・設置されている」って意味で"is put"って言ってたりして・・・）

Comment: As choco says, please clarify what you want to say in English. "Vending machines are regarded as positive things?" or "They are placed aggressively?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your teacher means 置かれている, the passive form of the verb 置く (to place, put). So the machines are put everywhere and are very visible to passers by. Just an idea.

By the way, I think the reason 見られている was highlighted is because it is the passive form of 見る, and it does not go well with the active nature of 積極的に. The object of viewing can't really be intentionally proactively being viewed, if that makes sense. It is either viewed or it isn't. But it could work with the passive form 置かれている because the machines are being placed there by companies in a proactive manner.

Comment: The comment was specifically about word choice, not grammar. But if 置くworks in that context, that was my first thought too. Just didn't know if it made sense. Thanks.